# Accessing Form object from different class

Tags: c#, forms

I am trying to access a Form's RichTextBox control via a separate class.

In my form class...

```
    delegate void SetTextCall(string s);

    public void safeCall(string s)
    {
        if (this.richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCall d = new SetTextCall(safeCall);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { s });
        }
        else this.richTextBox1.AppendText("From Applicator");
    }
```

In a different class...

```
public void getMessages()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> result = ScannerMessages
                .GroupBy(k => k.Value)
                .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
                .ToDictionary(grp => grp.First().Key, grp => grp.Skip(1).Select(k => k.Key).ToList());

            if(result.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(var key in result.Keys)
                {
                    // I want to write to the rich textbox the key and the list accosiated with the key 
                    // in the richtextbox on Form1
                }
             }
        }
    }
```

I have tried modifying the textbox to be public, and I tried tinkering with making a static method to call. I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Formerly, you must have reference to the first form class object in your second class.

Comment: What's wrong with your "safeCall" approach? You should introduce methods on your Form to allow manipulations from outside. It's not a good practice to make controls directly accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep your UI separate from your business logic.  This means that this class, which is performing a computation on some data, should know nothing at all about your UI, and should not know anything about a form or its contents.

Instead it should simply return the value, instead of having the method be void.  Then your UI can call this method, get the result, and then handle displaying that result however it feels it is necessary.

In addition to being easier, it greatly reduces coupling.  It prevents this class from being tied to just this one UI, and it allows the UI and business logic to be developed independently, without requiring either to have an intimate knowledge of the other.  This makes development easier, and it makes the program much easier to reason about, improving maintainability, easing debugging, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry if this was unclear- These are in two separate classes- I did not post the entire class, just the piece that is trying to access the richtextbox. If I would add the "public void getMessages()" to the Form1 class it would work without any issues. My safeCall works as intended. What I want to be able to do is have that safeCall() called from the seperate class without instantiating another Form1 object. I can't make safeCall() static or it breaks. From1.safeCall() is not valid from the other class.

Comment: @user3198872 My answer accounts for *all* of those points.  This code should not be in `Form1`, it should be in another class.  Neither it, nor any aspect of the form or it's contents should be static.  This method should know nothing about the form, whats in it, or how these results should be displayed.  It should simply return the results as the return value of this method.  The form, when it calls this method, is then responsible for displaying the results (as well as marshaling to the UI thread, if needed), not this method.  This is how you separate your UI from your business logic.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying. My problem comes in when the rest of the application comes into play. The messages in above post are actually in a reference class (like a "global" class). Those objects are then populated by other threads. Then the class that has the top segment of code is another thread that continually checks the status of those messages. If they change then I want it to populate the form. What direction should I take that to follow what you are saying?

Comment: @user3198872 Sounds like there should be an event near the top level of the non-UI code that is fired when the data changes, and the UI can then subscribe to that event and update the UI based on those changes.